# Allow access to Amazon AWS console using IAM

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to setup separate accounts using Amazon's IAM service what would allow two different users to access the Amazon web dashboard/console? I'd like a separate account that can access these pages but I'd prefer not to have to give away the keys to the kingdom to do so.

If so can IAM policies be specified to allow restrict what the user can do with the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a short howto on adding an ec2 user, it is similar for most policies.
URL:
http://www.corbettbaker.com/blog-posts/creating-aws-user-ec2-only-permissions

Basically, replace ec2user with whatever you want the user name to be.

-CB

Comment: Excellent write up. The tools are a moving target and this must have changed. Instead of 'iam-groupadd -g ec2 -v' I needed to use 'iam-groupcreate -g ec2 -v'. Thanks kindly for the help!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I probably copy+pasted from iam-groupadduser. Updating docs accordingly.

Comment: Hi there - any chance of a new link? I get a Google sites error these days for corbettbaker.com

Comment: Your blog posts returns 404.

Comment: This hasn't been necessary since 12', however, for historical purposes:http://web.archive.org/web/20111115054852/http://www.corbettbaker.com/blog-posts/creating-aws-user-ec2-only-permissions